# Запрос не с первой строки

Tags: php, mysql

Допустим, делаю вывод статей в цикле; подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли запрос

```
$post_all = mysql_fetch_array($post_query);
```

начинать не с первой строки, а например с 5

```
for($i=$page_start;$i<=$page_end;$i++)
{
$post_all = mysql_fetch_array($post_query);
echo '<div class="article">';
echo '<h2><a href="post.php?post='.$post_all['id'].'">'.$post_all['title'].'</a></h2>';
echo '<div class="text">'.$post_all['description'].'</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo $post_all['id'];
}
```

Comment: @technomaniak1 Чтобы добавить код, выделите его мышкой и нажмите на кнопку 101010.

Comment: <a href="http://hashcode.ru/questions/22506/постраничная-навигация-на-php">Подобный вопрос</a>.

Comment: Ща попробуем.

Comment: Один вопрос только возник: в таблице 16 записей для 1 стр делаю LIMIT 0,10 все ок, а для второй как только не пробовал: LIMIT 10,6 - так почему-то ничего не выводит. (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все разобрался, заработал LIMIT 10, 20 почему-то. Спасибо за ссылку - 50 строчек кода сэкономил.

Comment: LIMIT с_какой_записи, кол_во_записей

По идее LIMIT 10, 10 должно работать для второй страницы, ищите ошибку в другом месте.